# MySQL select compare numbers from space separated string

Tags: mysql, select, spaces

I have a `Resolution` column in a table where the resolution is space separted, eg: `1024 768`.

I want to select all rows that have the `width` (first number) between A and B.

How can I write something like this in MySQL?

Let's say A is 500 and B is 1200 and `resolution` is the name of the column.

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE first_value(resolution) > 500 AND first_value(resolution) < 1200.`

What can I use to get the `first_value` of the space separated string as a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) (See this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e40c2/1)):

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(resolution, ' ', 1) > 500 AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(resolution, ' ', 1) < 1200;
```

**Special note**: Please be aware that using this method will not be able to utilize any indexes on the table (This query will get much slower as the table grows larger). Because you need to split each row with a function, there is no way this query can use an index to filter this data. Ideally, you should split this data into two separate columns on insert (I'd take a look into using triggers, or possible modifying your code to insert the data differently), and filter the data that way.

Here is how you can do a simple trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `resolution` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `resolution_width` int(11) signed NULL,
  `resolution_height` int(11) signed NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) -- DON'T FORGET YOUR INDEX ON resolution_width and resolution_height
                     -- (Or all this will be for naught)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 //

--Be sure to add a similar one for BEFORE UPDATE if you're updating data as well
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger BEFORE INSERT ON `test`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.resolution_width = CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.resolution, ' ', 1) AS SIGNED),
    NEW.resolution_height = CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.resolution, ' ', -1) AS SIGNED);
END//

INSERT INTO `test` (`resolution`) VALUES ('1100 2200');
```

Comment: Apart from the fields not being indexed, is this method too slow to be used for about 10k rows? There is a lot of code that currently uses the string value in that column, that's the only reason why I don't really want to change it and the way data is inserted. Maybe I could duplicate the data and add `resolution_width` and `resolution_height` columns.

Comment: @Cristy Run it and find out.

Comment: Well, it might run fast on my NVMe SSD and be very slow on different servers, that I don't have access too. I will go with this solution for now as it's the quickest to implement test, if it turns out it's too slow I will add the extra columns.

Comment: Adding a trigger shouldn't be too terrible difficult. Let me edit my answer, and I'll put a simple script up that should demonstrate.

Comment: Do you know what version of MySQL was `SUBSTRING_INDEX` introduced in?

Comment: @Cristy According to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring_index.asp):  MySQL 5.7, MySQL 5.6, MySQL 5.5, MySQL 5.1, MySQL 5.0, MySQL 4.1, MySQL 4.0, MySQL 3.23

Comment: @Cristy I've updated my answer again to provide a simple trigger. **Be aware:** this will not work if your code inserts do not reference the columns to insert (As you are going to need to add new columns). ie. `INSERT INTO test VALUES (...)` will NOT work, whereas `INSERT INTO test (resolution) VALUES (...)` will work.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I just used your initial answer. The comparison was failing because the value was received via $_POST as a string. I had to use `intval($A)` so that the comparison worked as a number comparison, not a lexicographic comparison.

Comment: @Cristy Glad I could help